# WKHTMLTOPDF - borders appear on pdfs

Tags: html, css, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I have a web page of data that I export to a pdf using wkhtmltopdf 0.12.3.2 (with patched qt).

When the data is displayed on screen, it looks exactly as I want it to appear as shown below:

[image]

When the data is rendered to the pdf, a "ghost" border appear on the pdf as shown below:

[image]

And when I print out the data, more 'ghost' borders appear on the page, as shown below:

[image]

**How do I prevent these 'ghost' borders from appearing?** I have tried many options but the solution eludes me.

I have tried `outline: #fff solid medium !important;` but this has no effect. I have also tried `box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;` but this has no effect.

This issue only seems to occur with the CSS `border: double` value.

Here is my html code:

```
<div class="resumeStyleStandardHeadings8" dir="ltr" style="direction: ltr;">Summary Details</div>
```

Here is my css code:

```
.resumeStyleStandardHeadings8 {
    background: #000;
    border-left: 10px double #fff;
    border-bottom: 10px double #fff;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    outline: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%
}
```

Comment: For troubleshooting try: removing `box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;` & ` dir="ltr" style="direction: ltr;"`. And please experiment with adding additional divs. You may need to nest contents one more level deep. Also, could you inspect-element (in html view; of course) and tell us what the box-sizing is?

Comment: Also, does:  --disable-smart-shrinking /  --enable-smart-shrinking help? https://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt

Comment: admcfajn, thanks. I have tried all your suggestions, but the 'ghost' borders still appear. `--disable-smart-shrinking / --enable-smart-shrinking` does not appear to have any affect.

Comment: could you inspect-element (in html view; of course) and tell us what the box-sizing is? Changing border-box to content-box (&vice-versa) can make all the difference.

Comment: box-sizing is `border-box`. I have changed this to `content-box`, but the issue persists. This is very frustrating.

Comment: Does this have to be single-element solution? can you wrap `. resumeStyleStandardHeadings8` in another div? Or add one with `. resumeStyleStandardHeadings8:before{}`?

Comment: Unfortunately, this must be a single element solution.

Comment: This issue only seems to occur with `border: double` value.

Comment: I've answered below. The white inner border on the left seems to extend a bit too far vertically, but the blur/shadow is gone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `:before` to fix problems with wkhtmltopdf double-border and background-color causing drop-shadow / blur. box-model, rendering, anti-aliasing, bug

```
<div class="resumeStyleStandardHeadings8" dir="ltr" style="direction: ltr;">Summary Details</div>


.resumeStyleStandardHeadings8:before{
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width:100%;
  height:36px;
  margin-left:-9px;
  margin-top:-5px;
  background:#000;
  border-left: 2px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}
.resumeStyleStandardHeadings8 {
    display: block;
    outline: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    padding: 5px 2px;
    background: #000;
    border-left: 2px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}
```